# What is the difference of using COUNT() and FOUND_ROWS() if I don't use a LIMIT?

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference between using

```
SELECT COUNT()
```

against

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

I know found rows is supposed to be used when you have a limit but if you don't use a limit is there really any difference?

Answer (score 4):

You will get the same result but in two different ways.

COUNT() is an [aggregated function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) used when selecting and grouping data.

FOUND_ROWS() is a [information function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html) used *after* another select to get information on what happened.

If you only need the number of rows go with COUNT(), it's faster.

Like this:

```
select count(*) as number_of_rows from some_table where something = something group by something;
```

or

```
select * from some_table where something = something group by something;
select found_rows();
```

Comment: Thanks, just wondered as PDO doesn't support COUNT on select statements and FOUND_ROWS() works. Will accept when I can :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from tablename
```

Is the most efficient way to get the number of rows in table tablename

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows